# QProcess not work with start but work with startDetached

Tags: qt, windows-7, qprocess

I have a problem with start dos application with Qprocess::start.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess *process = new QProcess();
    process->start("c:\\femag\\wfemag_02-2013.exe");

    return a.exec();
}
```

the executed application fails at some point with this kind of error "invalid handle".

when I use

```
process->startDetached("c:\\femag\\wfemag_02-2013.exe");
```

the application starts OK. But I need to use process->start().

I tried this on windows7 32 or 64 bit with same issue. But in windows8 it is working ok.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: You can check what error it returned by process->error()

Comment: process->error()  return QProcess::UnknownError